# SwiperJS slide slides halfway and should not slide at all when user tabs off CTA button

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, swiper.js

We're having to add accessibility features to our site and while working on the SwiperJS to enable keyboard and mousewheel capabilities, I noticed the following. When a user tabs into the slider and has focus on the CTA button and then clicks tab again, the slide goes halfway. We need the slide not to slide at all. I'm aware of a similar discussion here on Stack Overflow, but my scenario is different.

Setting *loop* to false fixes it and prevents the slide from sliding, but that's not an option since the UX team want the slides to loop. Setting *slidesPerView* to auto as discussed in the other Stack Overflow discussion doesn't make a difference.

Update: We noticed when the slides cycle one time, meaning it displays all three slides and then returns to the first slide, normal behavior is experienced and the slide doesn't slide part of the way to the next slide.

```
;(function ($, window, document, undefined) {
    var sliders = [],
    pauseTimer,
    pauseTimerMarquee,
    isLoadVideo,
    config = {
        delay: 6000
    },
    selector = {
        bgHero: '.marquee-heading .marquee-item',
        marqueeHeadingContainer: '.marquee-heading',
        marqueeCarousalContainer: '.swiper-container-carousal',
        pagination: '.marquee-heading .swiper-pagination',
        playButton: '.marquee-play-icon-container',
        html5PlayButton: '.playpause',
        html5PlayInput: '.playPause',
        html5VideoContainer: '.html5-video-container, .video-overlay-container',
        html5Video: '.html5-video-container video'
    },
    
    options = {
        init: false,
        a11y: true,
        // Swiper will be disabled and hide navigation buttons on case there are not enough slides for sliding
        watchOverflow: true,
        //disableOnInteraction: true,
        navigation: {
            nextEl: null,
            prevEl: null,
            hideOnClick: true
        },
        pagination: {
            el: null,
            clickable: true
        },
        loop: true,
        keyboard: true,
        mousewheel: true
    },
               $(window).keyup(function (e) {
                    currentIDMarque = $(document.activeElement.closest('.swiper-container-carousal')).attr('id');
                    if($this.attr('id') === currentIDMarque) {                    
                        $('.marquee-heading').find('.swiper-slide').each(function(index, elm){
                            if(!$(this).hasClass('swiper-slide-active')) {
                                $(this).find('a').attr('tabindex',-1);
                            }else {
                                $(this).find('a').attr('tabindex',0);
                            }
                        });                                
                        if(typeof(currentIDMarque)!=='undefined') {
                            var isTabPressed = e.key === 'Tab' || e.keyCode === 9,
                                html5Video = $('.html5-video-container').find('video')[0];                            
        marqueeCarousalContainer: '.swiper-container-carousal',
                            focusableEls = Array.from( $(document.activeElement.closest('#'+currentIDMarque)).find('.swiper-slide-active a[href]:not([disabled]), .marquee-play-icon-container, .swiper-pagination-bullet, .swiper-button-prev, .swiper-button-next'));
                            if(isTabPressed &&  $(document.activeElement.closest('#' + currentIDMarque + ':focus-within')).length) {
                                slider.autoplay.stop();
                                if(e.shiftKey && isTabPressed) {                                
                                    focusableElsCount -=1;
                                    currentFocus = focusableEls[focusableElsCount];  
                                }else {
                                    currentFocus = focusableEls[focusableElsCount];                                                    
                                    currentFocus.focus();
                                    focusableElsCount +=1;
                                }
                            } 
                        }   
                        console.log(slider.autoplay);
                        slider.autoplay.play();
                    }
                });
```

Comment: This must be a very unique scenario.